# How can I copy the word which I am typing? (without mode switch...)

Tags: vim

Sometimes I want to set a starting mark then type a word(usually a long variable name), after finishing the word I may set an ending mark. Then I can get the word stored in my register so that I can paste it without any extra movement, mode switch, etc.

How can I make that? Or there is a better "vim-way" to achieve the similar effect?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following two mappings let you record any chunk of text you are typing in insert mode, not necessarily a single word, and save it into register `o`.

```
inoremap <C-K> <C-O>qo
inoremap <C-L> <Esc>q:let @o=@o[:-2]<CR>a
```

Start recording with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>, end recording with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. Paste the recorded text in insert mode with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> `o`.

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thank you. The vim script seems to be so powerful. I will try to learn that.

Answer (score 4):

In **INSERT** mode, you can use <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd> to trigger auto-completion.
It's very useful when you're re-typing long words.

Comment: See `:help i_ctrl-n` for more info.  You may need to tune you `complete` option too; for me I had to strip `i` out of it because it's too slow with thousands of files all circularly included...

Comment: I like the supertab plugin. We're so used to pressing tab in bash/zsh to autocomplete, it feels natural in a Vim buffer too.

Answer (score 2):

Use `m` and `y`.

1. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> (exit insert mode for 1 command)
2. Type `mk` to set marker `k` to your current location
3. Type your word
4. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
5. Type `` y`k `` to yank from marker `k` to your current location

http://www.marksanborn.net/software/using-markers-in-vim/

Comment: This requires dropping out of insert mode though.  Using Ctrl-O before steps one and three almost get you there; using a backtick instead of the single quote will do a part-line yank.

Comment: Whoops, that was a typo (the backtick). I'll update the post with both suggestions

Answer (score 0):

With `<C-o>`, you can temporarily leave insert mode for a single command. You can then issue a `yiw` command (yank inner word), and have the last word you've been typing in the default (or any other you specify with `"x`) register.